# Python to output to std::cin

Tags: python, c++

I am developing a python GUI for one cpp module. My question is, is it possible to get this gui to output to std::cin from cpp ? I tried using Popen but I cant figure out how it works. Also, is there any other way to output values from my python gui into the CPP ?

Example:
CPP

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <conio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void LaunchGui(bool &IsAlive){
    FILE* scr;
    Py_Initialize();

    scr = fopen("gui.py", "r");
    
    PyRun_SimpleFile(scr,"gui.py");
    fclose(scr);

    Py_Finalize();
    IsAlive = false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    bool IsAlive{true};
    int speed = 1;

    std::thread GuiThread(LaunchGui,std::ref(IsAlive));
    
    while(IsAlive){
        std::cin >> line;
        if(!line.empty() ){
            std::cout << line << std::endl;
        }  
    }
    GuiThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Python GUI

```
from tkinter import ttk
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI')
root.geometry("800x600")
root.minsize('800','600')
root.maxsize('800','600')
p = Popen(['test'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)

def Manual(value):
    print("From PythonGUI: " + str("send " + value))
    output = bytes(str(value), 'UTF-8')
    p.stdin.write(output)

Slider = Scale(root ,orient=HORIZONTAL,sliderlength = 25,from_=0,to=100,resolution = 1, label= "Value",font=("Ubuntu", 11),length= 500,command=Manual)
Slider.pack(side= TOP, anchor="w")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `cin` is only for input, not output. Are you asking if the module can provide fake input that will be read from `cin`?

Comment: Resolved with ZeroMQ